# Big data and data mining for CRM?

Tags: data-mining, bigdata, software-development

We are currently developing a customer relationship management software for SME's. What I'd like to structure for our future CRM is developing CRM with a social-based approach (Social CRM). Therefore we will provide our users (SME's) to integrate their CRM into their social network accounts. Also CRM will be enhance intercorporate communication of owner company.

All these processes I've just indicated above will certainly generate lots of unstructured data.

I am wondering how can we integrate *big data* and *data-mining* contepts for our project; especially for the datas generated by social network? I am not the expert of these topics but I really want to start from somewhere.

#### Basic capabilities of CRM (Modules)

-Contacts: People who you have a business relationship.

-Accounts: Clients who you've done a business before.

-Leads: Accounts who are your potential customers.

-Oppurtunites: Any business opportunity for an account or a lead.

-Sales Orders

-Calendar

-Tasks

What kind of unstructured data or the ways (ideas) could be useful for the modules I've just wrote above? If you need more specific information please write in comments.

Comment: I think this is too broad. You should say more about your requirements or constraints to narrow this down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two modules where you can really harness data mining and big data techniques are probably Leads and Opportunities. The reason is that, as you've written yourself, both contain 'potential' information that you can harness (through predictive algorithms) to get more customers. Taking Leads as an example, you can use a variety of machine learning algorithms to assign a probability to each account, based on that account's potential for becoming your customer in the near future. Since you already have an Accounts module which gives you information about your current customers, you can use this information to train your machine learning algorithms. This is all at a very high level but hopefully, you're getting the gist of what I'm saying.

Comment: Also I've thought the modules you've indicated could possibly generate datas that are suits for predicting. Your answer has been a confirmation for me. I got the gist. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Geop Solutions write blogs related to bigdata and CRM on weekly basis. You can read their blog at https://geopsolutions.wordpress.com/

Comment: This is almost a link-only answer since it doesn't provide any answer to the question directly here, and are discouraged on SE.